# Multiple Tables with same Field, Failed Constraint error

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am creating 3 tables containing the following fields
the problem is there are Constraint failed errors while inserting data in table 2 and 3

```
          TABLE 1                                           TABLE 2

|_id| name | class | sec | roll|               |_id| class | sec | doa |

           TABLE 3
|_id | class| sec | roll | aop | doa |
```

here is the code to generate the table

```
public static final String KEY_RID = "row_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "student_name";
public static final String KEY_ROLL = "student_roll";
public static final String KEY_SEC = "student_sect";
public static final String KEY_CLASS = "student_class";
public static final String KEY_DOA = "dayofattend";
public static final String KEY_AOP = "student_status";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "StudendtAttend";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "AttendTable";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "AttendDate";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE3 = "AttendAop";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    // Create Database
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_RID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_ROLL
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_CLASS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_SEC
                + " TEXT NOT NULL);");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE2 + " (" + KEY_RID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_CLASS
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_SEC + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_DOA + " TEXT NOT NULL);");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE3 + " (" + KEY_RID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_CLASS
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_SEC + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_ROLL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_DOA
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_AOP + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    }



// Insert Values into DB
public long populateDB(String roll, String name, String sec, String clas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_ROLL, roll);
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    cv.put(KEY_CLASS, clas);
    cv.put(KEY_SEC, sec);
    ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    populateDB2(roll, name, sec, clas );
    return (0);

}
public long populateDB2(String roll, String name, String sec, String clas) {
    ContentValues cv1 = new ContentValues();
    cv1.put(KEY_CLASS, clas);
    cv1.put(KEY_SEC, sec);
    ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, cv1);

    populateDB3(roll, name, sec, clas );
    return 0;

}
public long populateDB3(String roll, String name, String sec, String clas) {
    ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
    cv2.put(KEY_ROLL, roll);
    cv2.put(KEY_CLASS, clas);
    cv2.put(KEY_SEC, sec);
    ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE3, null, cv2);
    return(0);

}
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong, I can't quite get what.
Help please.

Comment: How are you inserting data? What exactly does the logcat say?

Comment: The code I am using for inserting is `code 
public long populateDB2(String roll, String name, String sec, String clas) {

  ContentValues cv1 = new ContentValues();

  cv1.put(KEY_CLASS, clas);

  cv1.put(KEY_SEC, sec);

  ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, cv1);

  
  populateDB3(roll, name, sec, clas );


  return 0; `

04-13 08:47:39.585: E/Database(333): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed

Comment: basically using the same method to insert values into all tables

Comment: post your inset codes, it is hard to read from comment.

Comment: code inserted, is it because I am using same variable names?
Sec and Class and Roll combined form my primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare all the columns not null, and when you insert in `populateDB2` you only insert values in only 2 columns the others are then null thus Constraint failed.
Also why 3 tables, if these are all your columns then 1 table is OK.

Comment: Thanks, I am feeling so dumb right now :D

Anyways this forum has really been very helpful, I have used this forum  numerous times, Thanks!

Comment: Well, sometimes you just miss the most obvious.

Comment: 2 tables to reduce redundancy , I may delete the table 2, but table 1 and 3 are in 3NF I guess. (Considering the fact that Class Section and Roll combined form the primary attribute in this table)

Comment: You can declare Class, Section and Roll together UNIQUE. Table 3 has all the columns in tables 1 and 2, so I do not think you need the first 2 tables.